# Consulta MySQL desde Python

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy buscando la forma de hacer una consulta a MySQL desde Python, para ello me estoy apoyando en la [documentación oficial](http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html?highlight=python#mysqldb). El problema es que aunque consigo conectarme y hacer la consulta sin problemas, soy incapaz de al recorrer los resultados, buscar los datos que me interesan por el nombre de la columna de la tabla.

Estoy usando:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="contra",db="basedatos")

c=db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tabla")
c.fetchall()

for juego in c:
    print(juego[26])
    pass
```

Es decir, quiero modificar `juego[26]` por `juego['Nombre']`, que sería el nombre de la columna. Esto más que nada es porque la estructura de la tabla puede cambiar y me obligaría a modificar el código cada vez que esto ocurriese. He intentado con comillas simples, dobles y paréntesis, y no me ha servido ninguna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes usar [MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html):

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="contra",db="basedatos")
c = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
result_set = c.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print(row["Nombre"])
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!